# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'appServlet'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I got this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'appServlet'

This is my servlet-context.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:di-context.xml"/>
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
        infrastructure -->
    <!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"/>
    </bean>
    <!--class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver" />-->

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/messages" /> </bean> -->
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.blogspot.feomatr.controller"/>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" -->
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
                <!-- Scan views directory for tiles configuration -->
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
</beans>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
            classpath:di-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My home

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHome(Model model) {
    log.info("showHome");
    return "home";
}
```

And Yes I have the file home.jsp in the path src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views
I'm not able to fixed it, someone can help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your request mapping like this..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHome(Model model) {
    log.info("showHome");
    return "home";
}
```

and add this in your spring-servlet.xml..

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. actually you can pass many values ,value = {'1','2',etc} but that is not the problem

Comment: @Natali Torres place the code snippet i have added in the post.

Comment: Welcome @Natali Torres ;)

Comment: Btw, do you know the answer of this))http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518171/how-do-i-convert-from-webconfig-java-to-web-xml

Comment: @NataliTorres please go through this link,, you wil get a idea. http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/