# How do I convert from WebConfig.java to web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I started a project in spring + mvn, then when project was created, two files too: SampleApplication.java and WebConfig.java, later I created a file web.xml inside the path:

> ../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

PS: I'm sure that my file is correct

The problem is when I execute mvn run, it recognized the SampleApplication.java and WebConfig.java and I wish that it can only recognized web.xml, how can I do this?

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets
  and Filters -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
      classpath:di-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Processes application requests -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My WebConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.lyncode.jtwig.mvc.JtwigViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="APP")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        JtwigViewResolver jtwigViewResolver = new JtwigViewResolver();
        jtwigViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        jtwigViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return jtwigViewResolver;
    }

}
```

My SampleApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Import(WebConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends entirely on what `SampleApplication` and `WebConfig` are and what is in `web.xml`. Please clarify.

Comment: This is a Spring boot app. The entry point is that `main` method. You need `SampleApplication`. If you want a standalone Servlet webapp, then you'll need to do that, with a dedicated servlet container.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, I don't get it completely, I'm beginner in this

Comment: @NataliTorres please go through this link,, you wil get a idea. http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/

Comment: @NataliTorres check your @ComponentScan(basePackages="APP") and do the other configurations